# Flickering Notif Bar

Tags: javascript, html, css, webflow

I'm not a dev just wanted to know how I can do this?

**Scenario:**

-I created the notif bar on top, and I wanted it the way it as it is right now as a sticky instead of a fixed element..
-The notification bar works the way it is intended to work. Once you close it, it shouldn't appear again on refresh.. (where the problem is)

**Problem:**
On refresh, the notif bar flickers..

**Question**
is there a way for it not to flicker as a sticky element? I know it works fine if it's set to Fixed, but i wanted it the way it is (pushing down the nav)..

http://mindatwork.webflow.com/

Here's the script I got from youtube.

```
<script>
$.getScript('https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/js-cookie@2/src/js.cookie.min.js', function() {
  var cookieName = 'notificationClosed';
  var cookieValue = 'userClosedIt';
  var cookieExpire = Number($('.bar-number').text());
  
  if(typeof Cookies.get(cookieName) !== 'undefined') $('.bar-collection-list').remove();
  $('.close').click(function() {
    Cookies.set(cookieName, cookieValue, { expires: cookieExpire });
  });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

wrap your code inside the `window.onload` so it will only execute your code after page loads.

```
window.onload = function(){
 $.getScript('https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/js-cookie@2/src/js.cookie.min.js', function() {
      var cookieName = 'notificationClosed';
      var cookieValue = 'userClosedIt';
      var cookieExpire = Number($('.bar-number').text());
      
      if(typeof Cookies.get(cookieName) !== 'undefined') {
         $('.bar-collection-list').remove();
       }
      $('.close').click(function() {
        Cookies.set(cookieName, cookieValue, { expires: cookieExpire });
      });
    });
  }
```

Comment: Still flickers :(